# Code returns error avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfb, arduino

Tags: arduino-ide

Not entirely my code, does not work most if the time. Need help in determining if this is a software or a hardware issue.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

void activateGreenLED();

Servo player1Servo;
Servo player2Servo;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4); // I2C address 0x27, SDA pin 20, SCL pin 21

const int player1ButtonPin = 2;
const int player2ButtonPin = 3;
const int startButtonPin = 4;
const int piezoPin = 7;  // Pin for the piezo buzzer

const int player1LEDs[] = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};
const int player2LEDs[] = {32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41};
const int redLED = 22;
const int blueLED = 32;
const int greenLED = 19;

int player1Score = 0;
int player2Score = 0;

void activateGreenLED() {
  digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);  // Turn ON the green LED
  delay(1000);  // Keep the green LED ON for 1 second
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);   // Turn OFF the green LED
}

// Melody data for the Super Mario Bros. theme
#define NOTE_B0  31
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46
#define NOTE_G1  49
#define NOTE_GS1 52
#define NOTE_A1  55
#define NOTE_AS1 58
#define NOTE_B1  62
#define NOTE_C2  65
#define NOTE_CS2 69
#define NOTE_D2  73
#define NOTE_DS2 78
#define NOTE_E2  82
#define NOTE_F2  87
#define NOTE_FS2 93
#define NOTE_G2  98
#define NOTE_GS2 104
#define NOTE_A2  110
#define NOTE_AS2 117
#define NOTE_B2  123
#define NOTE_C3  131
#define NOTE_CS3 139
#define NOTE_D3  147
#define NOTE_DS3 156
#define NOTE_E3  165
#define NOTE_F3  175
#define NOTE_FS3 185
#define NOTE_G3  196
#define NOTE_GS3 208
#define NOTE_A3  220
#define NOTE_AS3 233
#define NOTE_B3  247
#define NOTE_C4  262
#define NOTE_CS4 277
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_DS4 311
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_FS4 370
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_GS4 415
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_AS4 466
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define NOTE_C5  523
#define NOTE_CS5 554
#define NOTE_D5  587
#define NOTE_DS5 622
#define NOTE_E5  659
#define NOTE_F5  698
#define NOTE_FS5 740
#define NOTE_G5  784
#define NOTE_GS5 831
#define NOTE_A5  880
#define NOTE_AS5 932
#define NOTE_B5  988
#define NOTE_C6  1047
#define NOTE_CS6 1109
#define NOTE_D6  1175
#define NOTE_DS6 1245
#define NOTE_E6  1319
#define NOTE_F6  1397
#define NOTE_FS6 1480
#define NOTE_G6  1568
#define NOTE_GS6 1661
#define NOTE_A6  1760
#define NOTE_AS6 1865
#define NOTE_B6  1976
#define NOTE_C7  2093
#define NOTE_CS7 2217
#define NOTE_D7  2349
#define NOTE_DS7 2489
#define NOTE_E7  2637
#define NOTE_F7  2794
#define NOTE_FS7 2960
#define NOTE_G7  3136
#define NOTE_GS7 3322
#define NOTE_A7  3520
#define NOTE_AS7 3729
#define NOTE_B7  3951
#define NOTE_C8  4186
#define NOTE_CS8 4435
#define NOTE_D8  4699
#define NOTE_DS8 4978

int startMelody[] = {
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_G5, 0, 0, 0, NOTE_G4, 0, 0, 0, NOTE_C5, 0, 0, NOTE_G4, 0, 0, NOTE_E4, 0, 0, NOTE_A4, 0, NOTE_B4, 0, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_A4, 0, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, NOTE_G5, NOTE_A5, 0, NOTE_F5, NOTE_A5, 0, NOTE_G5, 0, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, 0, 0, 0
};
int noteDurationStart = 150;
const int noteDuration = 300;
const int notePause = 10;

void setup() {
  player1Servo.attach(5);
  player2Servo.attach(6);
  activateGreenLED();

  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor (0,0);  // Adjusted for 2x16 LCD
  lcd.print("Tug of War Game");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("Press START");

  pinMode(player1ButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(player2ButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(startButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(piezoPin, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize the green LED
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);

  // Activate the green LED at the beginning of the game
  activateGreenLED();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pinMode(player1LEDs[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(player2LEDs[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  activateGreenLED();  // Activate the green LED at the start of each game

  if (digitalRead(startButtonPin) == LOW) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Game Started!");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Press P1 or P2");

    playMelody(startMelody, sizeof(startMelody) / sizeof(startMelody[0]), noteDurationStart);  // Play melody when the game starts


    while (true) {
      if (digitalRead(player1ButtonPin) == LOW) {
        tugOfWar(player1LEDs, player2LEDs, redLED, blueLED, player1Servo, player2Servo, player1Score);
      }

      if (digitalRead(player2ButtonPin) == LOW) {
        tugOfWar(player2LEDs, player1LEDs, blueLED, redLED, player2Servo, player1Servo, player2Score);
      }

      if (player1Score >= 10) {
        displayWinner("Player 1 Wins!");
        playMelody(startMelody, sizeof(startMelody) / sizeof(startMelody[0]), noteDurationStart);  // Play melody when player 1 wins
        actuateServo(player2Servo);
        break;
      } else if (player2Score >= 10) {
        displayWinner("Player 2 Wins!");
        playMelody(startMelody, sizeof(startMelody) / sizeof(startMelody[0]), noteDurationStart);  // Play melody when player 2 wins
        actuateServo(player1Servo);
        break;
      }
    }

    // Play melody after the game is over
    playMelody(startMelody, sizeof(startMelody) / sizeof(startMelody[0]), noteDurationStart);
    delay(2000);  // Delay after the game for 2 seconds
    resetGame();   // Reset the game for a new round
  }
}

void tugOfWar(const int *activeLEDs, const int *inactiveLEDs, int activeColorLED, int inactiveColorLED, Servo &activeServo, Servo &inactiveServo, int &score) {
  digitalWrite(activeColorLED, HIGH);  // Activate the color LED (Red for Player 1, Blue for Player 2)

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    analogWrite(activeLEDs[i], 255);  // Turn ON active player's LED with full intensity
    playClickSound();  // Play click sound
    delay(100);

    analogWrite(activeLEDs[i], 0);   // Turn OFF active player's LED
    analogWrite(inactiveLEDs[i], 0);  // Turn OFF inactive player's LED
    delay(100);
  }

  activeServo.write(90);  // Move the active player's servo to the center position
  inactiveServo.write(90);  // Move the inactive player's servo to the center position

  digitalWrite(activeColorLED, LOW);  // Deactivate the color LED

  score++;  // Increase the score for the active player
  updateScoreDisplay();
  delay(1000);  // Delay for better visibility
}

void actuateServo(Servo &servo) {
  for (int pos = 90; pos >= 0; pos -= 5) {
    servo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  delay(2000);
  for (int pos = 0; pos <= 90; pos += 5) {
    servo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
}

void playClickSound() {
  tone(piezoPin, NOTE_B0, noteDuration);
  delay(notePause);
}

void updateScoreDisplay() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Score: ");
  lcd.print(player1Score);
  lcd.print(" - ");
  lcd.print(player2Score);
}

void displayWinner(const char *winnerMessage) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(winnerMessage);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Congratulations!");
  delay(3000);  // Display the winner message for 3 seconds
}

void playMelody(const int *melody, int length, int duration) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (melody[i] == 0) {
      noTone(piezoPin);
    } else {
      tone(piezoPin, melody[i], duration);
      delay(duration + notePause);
    }
  }
}

void resetGame() {
  player1Score = 0;
  player2Score = 0;
  updateScoreDisplay();
}
```

Thanks!

Tried to reset the arduino and exchanging ports but to no avail, i also have seen other answers that require pins not to be inserted in the tx0/rx0 ports, but i dont know if this would directly affect the outout of the program.